# Image inside div has extra space below the image

Tags: html, css, image

Why in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/BZeLR/4/) the height of the `div` is bigger than the height of the `img` ? There is a gap below the image, but it doesn't seems to be a padding/margin.

**What is the gap or extra space below image?**

```css
#wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:200px;
}
img {
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" />
</div>
```

[image: Image with a gap or white space under it]

Comment: Here's a good read on this issue: [The Strange <img> Gap In HTML](https://dev.to/christiankaindl/the-strange-img-gap-in-html)

Answer (score 887, accepted):

By default, an image is rendered inline, like a letter so it sits on the same line that a, b, c and d sit on.

There is space below that line for the [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) you find on letters like g, j, p and q.

[image: Demonstration of descenders]

You can:

- adjust the [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) of the image to position it elsewhere (e.g. the `middle`) *or*
- change the `display` so it isn't inline.

```css
div {
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#align-middle img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#align-base img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

#display img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="default">
<h1>Default</h1>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/VangoghStarry-night2.jpg/300px-VangoghStarry-night2.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div id="align-middle">
<h1>vertical-align: middle</h1>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/VangoghStarry-night2.jpg/300px-VangoghStarry-night2.jpg" alt=""> </div>
  
  <div id="align-base">
<h1>vertical-align: bottom</h1>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/VangoghStarry-night2.jpg/300px-VangoghStarry-night2.jpg" alt=""> </div>

<div id="display">
<h1>display: block</h1>
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f2/VangoghStarry-night2.jpg/300px-VangoghStarry-night2.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

---

The included image is public domain and [sourced](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Descender.png) from Wikimedia Commons

Comment: To be more precise, this happens b/c inline elements take up the space of their current `line-height`. Setting `line-height` to the desired dimension would also overcome the undesired whitespace.

Comment: Does "f" qualify as a descender?

Comment: @j08691 — Depends on the font.

Comment: Note that if you're using `vertical-align: bottom` or `middle`, if your image is small (smaller than the line height), you may start seeing mystery space appearing *above* the image instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17905827/why-does-my-image-have-space-underneath#answer-17905828:~:text=if%20your%20image%20is%20small%20(smaller,space%20appearing%20above%20the%20image%20instead. Reduced test case: https://jsbin.com/jotacipaqu/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Confirmed this with a test text/image and drawing a line in photoshop: https://imgur.com/a/kRKfRTt

Comment: @j08691 I think "f" would be an ascender (for most fonts, as Quentin alludes to): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascender_(typography)

Comment: A nice visual of an image inline with text is given by MDN here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#sect1

Answer (score 169):

Another option suggested in this [blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Jun/05/Unwanted-Padding-in-IE-Image-Rendering-in-div-Tag) is setting the style of the image as `style="display: block;"`

Comment: thanks. This also fixed a similar issue with space under a flash movie. (added display:block to embed/object tags)

Comment: or `inline-block` if you still want it to display inline as images normally do.

Comment: @Ian @Imperative `inline-block` does not seem to be working.

Comment: This, however, breaks `text-align:center`.

Answer (score 144):

### Quick fix:

To **remove the gap under the image**, you can:

- Set the [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property of the image to `vertical-align: bottom;`  `vertical-align: top;` or `vertical-align: middle;`
- Set the display property of the image to `display:block;`

See the following code for a live demo:

```css
#vAlign img {
  vertical-align :bottom;
}
#block img{
  display:block;
}

div {border: 1px solid red;width:100px;}
img {width:100px;}
```

```html
<p>No fix:</p>
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" /></div>

<p>With vertical-align:bottom; on image:</p>
<div id="vAlign"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" /></div>

<p>With display:block; on image:</p>
<div id="block"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" /></div>
```

---

### Explanation: why is there a gap under the image?

The gap or extra space under the image isn't a bug or issue, it is the default behaviour. The root cause is that images are replaced elements (*see [MDN replaced elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)*). This allows them to "act like image" and have their own intrinsic dimensions, aspect ratio....
Browsers compute their display property to `inline` but they give them a special behaviour which makes them closer to `inline-block` elements (as you can vertical align them, give them a height, top/bottom margin and padding, transforms ...).

This also means that:

> `<img>` has no baseline, so when images are used in an inline formatting
>   context with vertical-align: baseline, **the bottom of the image will be
>   placed on the text baseline.**
>   (*source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Interaction_with_CSS), emphasis mine*)

As browsers by default compute the vertical-align property to baseline, this is the default behaviour. The following image shows where the baseline is located on text:

[image: Location of the baseline on text]
*([Image source](https://material.io/design/typography/understanding-typography.html#type-properties))*

Baseline aligned elements need to keep space for the [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) that extend below the baseline (like `j, p, g ...`) as you can see in the above image. In this configuration, **the bottom of the image is aligned on the baseline** as you can see in this example:

```css
div{border:1px solid red;font-size:30px;}
img{width:100px;height:auto;}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" />jpq are letters with descender
</div>
```

---

This is why the default behaviour of the `<img>` tag creates a gap at the bottom of it's container and why changing the vertical-align property or the display property removes it as in the following demo:

```css
div {width: 100px;border: 1px solid red;}
img {width: 100px;height: auto;}

.block img{
  display:block;
}
.bottom img{
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

```html
<p>Default:</p>
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" />
</div>
<p>With display:block;</p>
<div class="block">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" />
</div>
<p>With vertical-align:bottom;</p>
<div class="bottom">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RECDV24.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: So this is why setting font-size to 0 does not work. or does it?

Comment: @Persijn it does. Like setting `line-height:0;` but I don't consider this as a good workaround compared to changing the vertical-align or display properties

Comment: Note, however, that some browsers don't respect `font-size:0`: they set the font size to the minimum size in the user settings.

Comment: Yes it seems a white space.

Comment: well,I think the `middle` `text-top` `sub` `super`position in the picture is not right.

Comment: @xianshenglu do you have another image that hilights the baseline and would be more accurate? I'd be glad to change the current one if you do.

Answer (score 53):

One can also nullify parent's line height:

```
#wrapper {
  line-height: 0;
}
```

All fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/FaPFv/

Comment: WARNING! this will also kill any text nodes in the #wrapper. as it will be inherited. But bonus points for that awesome fiddler! here it is updated with text nodes. http://jsfiddle.net/FaPFv/30/

Comment: Alternatively, font-size:0

Comment: @mfluehr Please do not copy substantive content from JSFIddle to Stack Overflow for someone else's code. JSFiddle does not publish a license and you do not have the legal right to publish someone else's code to Stack Overflow, which licenses its content under CC By-SA 4.0.

Answer (score 15):

All you have to do is assign this property:

```
img {
    display: block;
}
```

The images by default have this property:

```
img {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use several methods for this issue like

1. Using `line-height`

   ```css
   #wrapper {  line-height: 0px;  }
   ```
2. Using `display: flex`

   ```css
   #wrapper {  display: flex;         }
   #wrapper {  display: inline-flex;  }
   ```
3. Using `display:` `block`, `table`, `flex` and `inherit`

   ```css
   #wrapper img {  display: block;    }
   #wrapper img {  display: table;    }
   #wrapper img {  display: flex;     }
   #wrapper img {  display: inherit;  }
   ```

Comment: Please don't recommend the very sloppy `line-height` hack, or at least make it clear, why it is the worst "solution" of them all: the moment someone puts text next to the image (especially preformatted multi-line with BR tags), they will find themselves in a worse situation than they started out with.

Comment: This helped me of all the solutions most. However I have my wrapping div expanding now beyond the subject image, previously display inline block in the div fixed that. TY

Answer (score 5):

I used `line-height:0` and it works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, -1: that screws up text positioning, so if someone also puts some (esp. multi-line, say, with `<BR>`) text next to the image, they will have a mispositioned, overlapped/overhanging mess.

Answer (score 4):

I found it works great using display:block; on the image and vertical-align:top; on the text.

```css
.imagebox {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    height:88px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #999;
}
.container {
    width:600px;
    height:176px;
    background-color: #666;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.text {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: robotomeduim, sans-serif;
    vertical-align:top;
    
}

.imagebox img{ display:block;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="imagebox">
        <img src="http://machdiamonds.com/n69xvs.jpg" /> <span class="text">Image title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="imagebox">
        <img src="http://machdiamonds.com/n69xvs.jpg" /> <span class="text">Image title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="imagebox">
        <img src="http://machdiamonds.com/n69xvs.jpg" /> <span class="text">Image title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="imagebox">
        <img src="http://machdiamonds.com/n69xvs.jpg" /> <span class="text">Image title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="imagebox">
        <img src="http://machdiamonds.com/n69xvs.jpg" /> <span class="text">Image title</span>
    </div>
    <div class="imagebox">
        <img src="http://machdiamonds.com/n69xvs.jpg" /> <span class="text">Image title</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

or you can edit the code a [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/v53tr53y/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I just added `float:left` to div and it worked

Comment: This is because setting `float:left` causes `display:block`

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `overflow: hidden;` for the container, and increase the height of the image to > 100%. `height: 100%;`