# How do I get a link to properly contain an image?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/C4dsE/)

### Screenshot

[image]

### Source

```
<a href="#"><img width="200" height="200"></a>
```

### Question

Notice how the black border only appears around the bottom part of the image? How do I fix that so that it appears around the whole thing?

I've done it before, but I can't remember how...

Comment: Wow...5 answers within 5 seconds of each other.  Fiddle is an awesome little tool.  The anchor tag height looks like its based on the text height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    <img width="200" border="0" height="200" />
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    border:1px solid black;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
img
{
   display: block;   
}
```

Live demo can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C4dsE/2/)

It is probably better to edit the border of the `<img>` tag instead of the `<a>`

Comment: floating it is the only method that got rid of the spacing at the bottom of the image too.

Comment: @Niels: Rather than just posting a link can you post the actual code required to solve the problem and provide the link for reference.  If the link were to break your answer would have become useless. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I'll do that in the future. I'm new to stackoverflow, so will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Mark I found that floating didn't remove the extra space, but adding line-height: 0; to the A element did, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532870/extra-padding-on-linked-images-in-every-broswer).

Answer (score 2):

You can use either:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/C4dsE/1/).

Or,

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/C4dsE/3/).

Of the two, it's likely that `inline-block` is more appropriate to your need (and even [Internet Explorer 6 and 7 should play nicely](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t03) with it, since `a` is 'naturally `display: inline`').

Comment: neither of those render correctly in FF. inline block shows as a dot, and block shows as a line a black line. in IE inline-block works, but it leaves a gap between the image and bottom border, wheras the block leaves a gap and fills the full width (which I guess isn't too bad because I could explicitly set the width).

Answer (score 1):

add a `display: inline-block` to your `a`

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS put

```
display:block;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

on you `a` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Put the border around the image like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/nmhAs/

```
img {
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: issue isn't just the border. i wanted to learn how to contain the element properly.